# Null Data Returned with Nested Relation in Room Database Android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

Given that I have 3 entities, `Order` contains list of `LineItem`, each *LineItem* will associates with one `Product` by *productId*.

The problem that when I get data from OrderDao, it returns null for the `product` field, but in the `lineItem` field, it has data. While I can data with ProductWithLineItem.
Already tried a lot of work arounds but it does not work.
Here is my code for entities and dao

#### Entities

```
@Entity(tableName = DataConstant.ORDER_TABLE)
data class Order(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "orderId")
    val id: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    var status: String
)
```

```
@Entity(tableName = DataConstant.LINE_ITEM_TABLE)
data class LineItem(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lineItemId")
    val id: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "productId")
    val productId: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "orderId")
    val orderId: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "quantity")
    var quantity: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "subtotal")
    var subtotal: Double
)
```

```
@Entity(tableName = DataConstant.PRODUCT_TABLE)
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productId")
    val id: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    var name: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    var description: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    var price: Double?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "image")
    var image: String?,

    )
```

#### Relations POJOs

```
data class ProductAndLineItem(
    @Embedded val lineItem: LineItem?,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "productId",
        entityColumn = "productId"
    )
    val product: Product?
)
```

```
data class OrderWithLineItems(
    @Embedded var order: Order,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "orderId",
        entityColumn = "orderId",
        entity = LineItem::class
    )
    val lineItemList: List<ProductAndLineItem>
)
```

#### Dao

```
@Dao
interface OrderDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM `${DataConstant.ORDER_TABLE}` WHERE orderId = :id")
    fun getById(id: String): Flow<OrderWithLineItems>
}
```

## Result after running with Dao

[Result after running query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LusF2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is my code for entities and dao

You code appears to be fine, with the exception of returning a Flow, testing, using your code, but on the main thread using List (and no WHERE clause) i.e the Dao being :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ${DataConstant.ORDER_TABLE}")
@Transaction
abstract fun getOrderWithLineItemsAndWithProduct(): List<OrderWithLineItems>
```

Results in :-

[image]

The data being loaded/tested using :-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    orderDao = db.getOrderDao()
    orderDao.clearAll()

    orderDao.insert(Product("product1","P1","desc1",10.01,"image1"))
    orderDao.insert(Product("product2","P2","desc2",10.02,"image2"))
    orderDao.insert(Product("product3","P3","desc3",10.03,"image3"))
    orderDao.insert(Product("product4","P4","desc4",10.04,"image4"))
    orderDao.insert(Product("","","",0.0,""))

    val o1 = orderDao.insert(Order("Order1","initiaited"))
    val o2 = orderDao.insert(Order("Order2","finalised")) // Empty aka no List Items

    val o1l1 = orderDao.insert(LineItem(10,"product3","Order1",1,10.01))
    val o1l2 = orderDao.insert(LineItem(20,"product4","Order1",2,20.08))
    val o1l3 = orderDao.insert(LineItem(30,"","Order1",3,30.09))
    val o1l4 = orderDao.insert(LineItem(40,"","x",1,10.01))
    //val o1l3 = orderDao.insert(LineItem(30,"no such product id","Order1",10,0.0))
    // exception whilst trying to extract if not commented out at test = ....
    val TAG = "ORDERINFO"
    val test = orderDao.getOrderWithLineItemsAndWithProduct()

    for(owl: OrderWithLineItems in orderDao.getOrderWithLineItemsAndWithProduct()) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Order is ${owl.order.id} status is ${owl.order.status}")
        for(pal: ProductAndLineItem in owl.lineItemList) {
            Log.d(TAG,"\tLine Item is ${pal.lineItem.id} " +
                    "for Order ${pal.lineItem.orderId} " +
                    "for ProductID ${pal.lineItem.productId} " +
                    "Quantity=${pal.lineItem.quantity} " +
                    "Product description is ${pal.product.description} Product Image is ${pal.product.image} Price is ${pal.product.price}")
        }
    }
```

As such I believe the issue might be that for some reason the Flow is detecting when the first query has completed but prior to the underlying queries.

That is when using @Relation the core objects (Order's) are extracted via the query and the core objects created then the related objects are extracted by a another query and used to build ALL the related objects as a List (unless just the one when it doesn't have to be a list). So prior to this underlying query the core object will have a null or an empty list for the underlying objects. Of course with a hierarchy of @Relations then this is replicated along/down the hierarchy.

I would suggest temporarily adding `.allowMainThreadQueires` to the databaseBuilder and using a `List<OrderWithLineItems>` or just a sole `OrderWithLineItems`. If using this then you get the Product(s) then the issue is with the Flow (which is what I suspect).

Comment: Not tried this yet but thank you @MikeT  for your deeply explanation for this case.  About the performance, query on the main thread might not good, is there any way for optimization for this case?

Comment: Already fixed this. The issue is because I forgot to insert the product data while writing test. The Flow works well and not a problem. Once again thank you @MikeT for the answer